# Is this XML legal and can I generate XSS for it?

Tags: php, xml, xsd, nested, categories

Can I write XSD schema for this? Please note that the **category** is repeated inside other category (same name). (Sorry I'm new to XML Schemas.)

```
<list>
        <category name="...">
                <category  name="Cats">
                    <subcategory>Syamese</subcategory>
                </category>
        </category>
        <category name="...">
                <category  name="Dogs">
                    <subcategory>Fox Terier</subcategory>
                </category>
        </category>
</list>
```

My current XSD has the following, but it's only good for only one category wrapper.

```
<xs:element name="category">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="category">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:element ref="category"/>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="subcategory"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I know I'd better rename one of the category's. But can I do this anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's legal. Perhaps not convenient. Think of XHTML. You can nest div in div in div... just like your category in category.

Your're missing the list element part in your XSD.